# Has man ever observed the spectrum of a single hydrogen atom?

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, atoms, hydrogen, orbitals

Were there this kind of experiment done before?

The spectrum we observed is radiated by huge number of hydrogen atoms in the gas, not by single hydrogen atom.

I know it's very hard to test a single atom.

Comment: As long as the hydrogen atoms in the gas are not interacting much, the fact that there are lots of them really doesn't matter too much.

Comment: And, while not hydrogen atoms, many groups are looking at the spectra from single crystal defects, such as the nitrogen-vacancy and silicon-vacancy complexes in diamond. Those are truly isolated.